# Appending Text to a TextArea over time (with delay)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a TextArea that I would like to be able to append characters or words to over a period of time. I tried using Thread.sleep() but then quickly realized this was horribly wrong.

I guess in pseudo-pseudocode

```
textArea.appendText("hey");
mysteryWaitMethod(500);
textArea.appendText("delayed");
```

Comment: +1 for quickly realizing the Thread.sleep() is horribly wrong for this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX does have a timer built in - it's called a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html). It's simple, straightforward, and provides extra functionality like Swing's `Timer` class, and, most importantly, executes code on the UI thread.

I don't know much about JavaFX directly, but generally you want things that modify the UI executing on the UI thread.  That's what this class does... I'd recommend using it over `java.util.Timer` (use that for background tasks... not UI ones).  When multiple threads try to mess with a UI, bad things tend to happen (which is the reason for these timers).

This post provides a good example of how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9966213/1515592

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a safer and more effective answer for my application. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the javax.swing.Timer

```
textArea.appendText("hey");

int delay = 500; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         textArea.appendText("delayed");
     }
 };
 Timer t = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
 t.setRepeats(false);
 t.start();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Or java.util.Timer

```
new Timer().schedule(
    new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textArea.appendText("delayed");
        }
}, 500);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Is there not a JavaFX equivalent? I was hoping to entirely stay away from Swing, just on the principle of it, but if I need to use the Timer class I will. Thanks!